# Memory leak in kotlin due to Closures?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-management, memory-leaks, textwatcher

I have a basic understanding of memory management in Kotlin i.e. local variables are stored in the stack and are managed by the OS and the objects are created on the heap and JVM manages them. Moreover, objects are passed as copy of reference and primitive types are passed as copy in functions.

In the below code, I have created a TextEditOperation function that creates an EditText programmatically and sets its properties using an instruction object and added a TextWatcher to it and at last added the edittext view to parent relative layout.

```
public fun TextEditOperation (pInstructionSetIndex: Int, pInstructionIndex: Int): View? 
{
    val instruction: InstructionKernelAndroid
    val context: Context?
    val activity: Activity
    val textedit: EditText
    val parent_view: RelativeLayout

    // fetch the instruction
    instruction = InstructionSetMgr.uAndroidOSInstructionSetList[pInstructionSetIndex][pInstructionIndex]

    // get activity's Context
    context = ProcessStates.GetMainActivityContext ()

    // cast activity's context to activity to use it's method
    activity = context as Activity

    // get parent view
    parent_view = activity.findViewById (instruction.GetParentID ()) as RelativeLayout

    // create view
    textedit = EditText (context)

    // set view properties

    textedit.id = instruction.GetElementID ()
    textedit.hint = instruction.GetHintText ()
    textedit.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (
        instruction.GetWidth (),
        instruction.GetHeight ()
    )
    textedit.x = instruction.GetX ()
    textedit.y = instruction.GetY ()
    textedit.setBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor (instruction.GetBackgroundColor ()))
    textedit.setTextColor (Color.parseColor (instruction.GetTextColor ()))
    
    // create and add a TextWatcher to the EditText

        val text_watcher: TextWatcher

    text_watcher = object : TextWatcher {
    
        override fun beforeTextChanged (s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int)
        {
            
        }
    
        override fun onTextChanged (s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) 
        {
            TextChanged (pInstructionSetIndex + 1, textedit.length (), textedit.id)
        }
    
        override fun afterTextChanged (s: Editable)
        {
            
        }
    } 
    // add the textwatcher
    textedit.addTextChangedListener (text_watcher)
    
    // add view to parent view
    parent_view.addView (textedit);

    return textedit;  
}
```

Now, what I understand is if the text_watcher object wouldn't have been there, then for line

> textedit = EditText (context)

EditText(context) object would have been created on the heap(managed by JVM) and variable textedit (managed by OS) refering the object would have been on stack. So the textedit variable would have been cleared from the stack memory by the OS once the function scope ends.

However, now as I am using the textedit variable inside the OnTextChanged function of the text_watcher:

```
override fun onTextChanged (s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) 
{
     TextChanged (pInstructionSetIndex + 1, textedit.length (), textedit.id)
}
```

And the onTextChanged function will get called much after the TextEditOperation's function scope has ended still How I'm able to access the length and id of the EditText using textedit variable which should have been removed by the OS by now?

Is it because of [closures](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closures-in-kotlin/) in kotlin, than I'm able to access the varible that's present in the outer scope and hence it not getting free by the OS thus being a memory leak, if yes how to fix it or is there any other reason behind it?

Comment: There is no memory leak here. As you said yourself, objects are passed around as references, by copying. This is exactly what's happening here. Your implementation of `TextWatcher` gets a copy of the object reference represented as `textedit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Disclaimer:** This answer focuses on Kotlin when targeting the JVM. The general concepts should be applicable to other platforms, but the specifics are likely to differ.*

---

## Closures & Variable Capturing

When a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) makes use of a variable from the enclosing scope, that closure "captures" the value of the variable *at the time the closure is created*.

In Kotlin, this is implemented by implicitly adding a *class property* to the class generated for the closure object. The property is initialized with the value of the captured variable during instantiation of the closure. Within the closure's scope, any time it looks like you are using the captured variable you are actually using the property. All this is done for you by the compiler behind the scenes.

So, using `textedit` inside your `TextWatcher` implementation is perfectly okay.

- The value of that variable is captured when the `TextWatcher` is created, not when the variable is first "used" in the implementation.
- All references to `textedit` within the scope of the `TextWatcher` implementation are actually referencing a hidden, implicitly defined property of said implementation. Meaning there is no attempt to access a local variable after it has been popped off the stack.

Note that when a closure references a *class property* of its enclosing class, the closure actually captures the instance of the enclosing class (i.e., `this`) instead of the value of the property directly. Also, unlike Java, Kotlin is capable of capturing mutable local variables (i.e., `var`), which it accomplishes by using a hidden "wrapper class" that wraps the actual value, then captures that wrapper object instead.

### Conceptual Example

Here is some code demonstrating the concept of what the compiler is doing. This is not necessarily *exactly* how variable capturing is implemented, but it should hopefully help with understanding the idea.

If you have something like this:

```kotlin
interface Printer {
    fun print()
}

fun createPrinter(): Printer {
    val message = "Hello, World" // local variable
    return object : Printer {
        override fun print() = println(message)
    }
}
```

After compilation, it would be as if you wrote the following:

```kotlin
interface Printer {
    fun print()
}

fun createPrinter() : Printer {
    val message = "Hello, World" // local variable
    class AnonymousPrinterImpl(
        private val message: String // class property
    ): Printer {
        // Here, 'message' is referring to the class property,
        // not the local variable.
        override fun print() = println(message)
    }
    return AnonymousPrinterImpl(message)
}
```

If you want to see what the compiler actually generates then you can inspect the Java byte-code via the [`javap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/javap.html) tool. Note that the implementation for an anonymous object is different than for a functional interface or lambda expression, but the end result is the same: A class property is implicitly added to the closure's class.

---

## Memory Management

In Kotlin, heap memory is managed by a garbage collector. At a high level, the way a garbage collector works is by periodically traversing the current object graph, starting at designated root objects. Any object that *cannot* be reached from those root objects is eligible for garbage collection. In languages with a garbage collector, a "memory leak" occurs when an object remains strongly referenced after the program no longer needs it. The strong reference prevents the unneeded object from being collected by the garbage collector.

You seem to be worried the `TextWatcher` is erroneously keeping the `TextEdit` object in memory after your function returns. But you are returning the `TextEdit` object from the function *and* adding it to some "parent view". Both those things strongly indicate the `TextEdit` object is still needed by your program after the function returns.

Additionally, the only strong reference to the `TextWatcher` after your function returns is by the `TextEdit`. In this case, it is not the `TextWatcher` keeping the `TextEdit` in memory, but rather the other way around. When the `TextEdit` becomes eligible for garbage collection, so will the `TextWatcher`. The circular reference between the two does not change that.

In short, there is no memory leak in your code; or at least not one caused by the `TextWatcher` based on what you have shown us.

Comment: I understood most of the part you said except this line "Your TextWatcher implementation is "capturing" the value of the local variable when it is instantiated". How can the TextWatcher capture the value of the local variable on being instantiated, it will capture it when the onTextChanged method of the TextWatcher will be called first time, which is much later but by then the function scope has already ended.

Comment: Capturing is implemented by the compiler. It sees that your local variable has been used in a closure so it implicitly copies the reference into an invisible property of the closure. It doesn’t matter when you actually use it because that invisible property is populated when the closure is instantiated. If your local property is a `var` it will still work because the compiler will actually create an invisible wrapper class instance for the local property and capture that instance in closures that use the local property. One of the neat features Kotlin has that Java doesn’t.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Always wondered: Will Kotlin _always_ use an invisible wrapper class for `var`, or only when the `var` is not effectively final (as defined by Java, at least)?

Comment: I’ve never dug in to see if they make an optimization there.

Comment: @Jatinguglani I updated my answer. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: @Slaw, it's clearer now, Is the any documentation that mentions the same that "The value of that variable is captured when the TextWatcher is created, not when the variable is first used in the implementation." and "In Kotlin, this is implemented by implicitly adding a class property to the class generated for the closure object."?

Comment: Capturing is mentioned a few times in Chapter 4 and 8 of the _Kotlin Language Specification_, though not in great detail from what I found. Not sure if the Kotlin docs mention it. Regardless, capturing state is how closures work by definition. As for how it's implemented on Kotlin/JVM, that's an implementation detail and may not be documented anywhere publicly. But given how scope, the stack, and the heap all work on the JVM, I struggle to see another way to implement it.

Comment: @Jatinguglani And as an aside, note that some languages, such as C++, do let you define lambdas that capture local variables _by reference_, which can lead to obvious problems if not careful. Kotlin is designed to be overall safer with regards to memory, though at the cost of flexibility.